# Express controller not returning cookie

Tags: express, cookies, jwt

This code snippet is part of a Express route for handling a user login. Everything goes fine but the response never gets returned. The console.log before the return statement returns a token so i know the jwt is signing a token properly, and everything else before that is working fine. But between the console and the return statement the response just hangs and the function times out. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
User.findOne({ email }, { _id: 1, name: 1 })
    .then(user => {
        jwt.sign({
            _id: user._id,
            name: user.name
        }, authSecret, { expiresIn: "3d" }, (err, token) => {
            if(err) return res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });

            console.log(`Token signed: ${token}`);

            return res.status(201).cookie("accessToken", token, {
                httpOnly: true,
                maxAge: 3*24*60*60*1000,
                signed: true,
                secure: true
            });
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.status` and `.cookie` just *prepare* the response to be sent. You need to call [`.send`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) or at least [`.end`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.end) to actually *send* the response.